# NGINX - Pointing a subdomain to a different directory that is not a subdirectory of the domain directory

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin, reverse-proxy

I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy with Apache. I have a domain, let's say `example.com` that is pointing at the `/var/www/html/example` directory.

I want to point a sub-domain `phpmyadmin.example.com` to a directory `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin` that is clearly not a sub-directory of the domain's directory.

My complete configuration file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example` is shown below. I added the parts between `##### BEGIN ..` and `###### END ..` to my configuration file to try to make this work.

Then I did `sudo service nginx restart` to restart NGINX successfully but I still cannot access `phpmyadmin.example.com`.

Here's my configuration:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/example;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com;

        access_log /var/www/html/example/access.log;
        error_log /var/www/html/example/error.log;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

##### BEGIN PHPMYADMIN CONFIG    #####
server {
    root /var/www/html/phpmyadmin;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name phpmyadmin.example.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
###### END OF PHPMYADMIN CONFIG #####

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;

    server_name example.com www.example.com
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: your config seems right. but sites-enabled is not the place to configure domains, so sites-available is.

Comment: What happens when you access `http://phpmyadmin.example.com`?

Comment: I get this error message: _Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at_ `phpmyadmin.example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem and I am going to list out the steps I took to resolve the issue as future reference for others:

## NGINX Configuration

The nginx configuration I tried initially was correct (as posted in the question).

## Adding a `CNAME` record into DNS entries

This was the major missing piece. I added a `CNAME` entry into my DNS dashboard as follows:

Type: `CNAME`    Name: `phpmyadmin`   Value: `example.com`   TTL: `3600` (can also set as automatic)

## Expanding SSL Certificate

I use `certbot` for the SSL certificate, and I had to regenerate it to include the domain in the certificate.

`sudo certbot --nginx -d example.com -d www.example.com -d phpmyadmin.example.com`

During this step, certbot can take care of the nginx configuration to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS.

## Reload NGINX service

Reloaded the new configuration: `sudo service nginx reload`

And verified the service status: `sudo service nginx status`

Everything is working well now.